# Android answer call: answerRingingCall()

Tags: android

i have an issue with Answer Incoming Call. I want to answer the call imediately while it's ringing

- I've added 4 permissions into Manifest file:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></usepermission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
  ```
- I used telservices.answerRingingCall(); in class myphonelistener extends PhoneStateListener
  where: ITelephony telservices=getTeleservices();

  ```
  switch (state) {
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          ITelephony telservices=getTeleservices();
          if(telservices!=null){
              try {
                  char[] ch=number.toCharArray();
                  if((ch[4]=='6' && ch[5]=='8' &&ch[6]=='8')){
                  AudioManager md;

                  md=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                  int ringermodee=md.getRingerMode();
                  md.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                      while(telservices.isRinging()){

                      telservices.answerRingingCall();
                      }
                  md.setRingerMode(ringermodee);
                  }

                  //telservices.enableDataConnectivity();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 1000)
                  .show();
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

          break;


          default:
          break;
     }
  ```

But seems cannot use permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

because of system permission, how to solve this, anyhelp? thanks!

Comment: you forgot the `"` after `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` in `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE</usespermission>` is that just copy-paste error or is it like this in your manifest?

Comment: just copy-paste error, if it's in my manifest, how can i run program ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1