# auto accepting call in android app

Tags: android

I want to learn how calls can be accepted programmatically in Android. For example, this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dungelin.smartcallaccept&hl=en) accepts calls on a hand wave motion.

I know how to dial a call from an app, but what API is available in Android to accept a call ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check out a [tutorial like this](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86) or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) and look into **Broadcast Receivers**.

For answering calls, check out [this](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1).

Doing so might require you to add a reciever to your Android Manifest and then implementing the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Ex:

**Android Manifest**

```
<application>
  .....
  <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

**ServiceReceiver**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to accept the call .. not just detect whether the phone is ringing

Comment: Is there a more recent tutorial ? Does the code for answering calls work in Android 4.4.2 (it was posted in 2010) ?

Comment: Maybe you can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1).