# How to use Intent.ACTION.ANSWER?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android development and trying to make an app with 2 buttons, one calls a specific number and the other just answers the phone when being called. Except I don't really know what to define in the ACTION_ANSWER area.. Thanks in advance!

**My MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0634834906"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent answerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you want to use button 2 to answer the call because when you get called there is already android will give option to pick up call, and it will not show your app when you got call

Comment: this might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1

Comment: @HarshParikh did you found the solution?