# How to activate and save voice mails to internal memory from android app?

Tags: android, sms, message, voice

I have a requirement for android app. Its like an automatic answering machine for unanswered voice calls in an android phone.

Suppose I got a call and I am not in a position to answer the call and if I have installed the application and turn on the feature of Auto Answering Machine (AAM) feature. It will respond on behave of me and leaves a voice message -  like "I am unable to take call, please leave your voice message after beep sound and press # to send the recorded voice message."

I am concerned about the feature it self, whether the voice message option can be controlled by the application (our own app)?

As far as I know that, it completely have rights by the network providers and I know that some of phones in US have an option to control voice mails or messages.

Also, my requirements includes saving the recorded voice mails or messages into my phone's local memory or else external storage device.

Am not sure like whether it is possible or not.

Am looking for your answers on how can I approach for the same.

I just googled it and could not able to get a desired result.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically answer/end a call in Android 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1)

Comment: @corsair992 the link what you have specified is for answering the calls programatically, but my question was how to activate the voice mails and then record the voice message sent without any network operator dependence.