# Answering a call automatically

Tags: android, incoming-call

I'm working on a answering machine and I"ve looked at multiple threads here and also in Google. Everybody seems to indicate that it is possible, then not possible, then one more method of doing it and so on.

Finally the thread seems to answer why it's not working is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28550533/5662769

Is this indeed correct for latest versions?

If yes, how come there are still a plethora of answering machines available in Google Play? They're all surely not by phone manufacturers?

Or am i missing something. I've gotten a terrible headache looking through similar answers which don't seem to work at all....