# Swipe imageview left and right in android

Tags: swipe

I have Imageview in center of screen.

I want to swipe Imageview left and right of the screen.How can i implement this?

Comment: you can go through:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1

or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop
based on your needs.

Comment: I have code of accept and reject call i want to implement swipable view how can i implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView .

It has open source implementation of glowpadview.

you can use it as a reference and change icons as per your need. It should create that swipable view.

Comment: Thanks its working but how to resize it? In small device it does not fit.

Comment: After 2 days when i open my project i got this error and Glowpadview is not launching. Application is crashed what should i do?                     The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.fima.glowpadview.GlowPadView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

Comment: I am not very sure but I think Its simple UI library so maybe try  making sure that all dependencies in your project are proper. This library should be there as a dependency of your main project. It should have no other problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for some very simple solution to this. I just needed left/right swipe. I found many solutions which were overly complicated. So I reduced what I found as much as I can and came up with something really simple (the swipe will work on a div with ID mainarea in this example, swipes are detected for minimum 100px to either side):

```
var swipe={
 startx:0,touch:function(event) {
 if (typeof event.touches!=='undefined') {
   switch (event.type) {
    case 'touchstart':swipe.startx=event.touches[0].pageX;
    case 'touchend':
     if(Math.abs(swipe.startx-event.changedTouches[0].pageX)>100)
      swipe.startx<event.changedTouches[0].pageX?window.location.href=swipe.prev:window.location.href=swipe.next
   }
  }
 },init:function(prev,next){
  swipe.prev=prev;
  swipe.next=next;
  document.getElementById("mainarea").addEventListener('touchstart',swipe.touch,false);
  document.getElementById("mainarea").addEventListener('touchend',swipe.touch,false);
 }
}
swipe.init(<previous page>,<next page>);
```