# How to Use PreciseCallState

Tags: android

I am making an App that should be able to detect call state, earlier I was advised to use `PreciseCallState` since by default android cannot detect exactly what state the call is in, `PreciseCallState` is in the Telephony Extension, which is in the [android_frameworks_base](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base), how to I get my Imports to work?, and for the most part will this work on Android  < 5 or its only 5>?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the "Android Hidden/Internal SDK" (or "API"), as it's called on the Internet. Search Google for that, it will answer some questions you might have (which I no longer remember too much). A place to get started immediately with it would be this: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api. Have fun messing with the internal SDK!

By the way, just a note. Google blocked the internal APIs from Android Pie onwards: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces. There are also ways to get past those anyway xD: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55970138/8228163 (or search for "bypass android hidden/internal sdk limitations").

Or you could also go with reflection and not use the internal SDK at all. Though, I still prefer the SDK. When I update the SDK, if some class/method/constant is no longer on it, Android Studio will throw a compilation error and I will know I must go find a replacement immediately - won't happen with reflection. (Aside from having the documentation right there and just calling a function instead of trying magic with hidden functions and try/catch things which I don't like too much in these cases.)

("Internal" because of android.internal.*, and "Hidden" because of the "@hide" attribute on classes/methods/constants.)

Answer (score -1):

But the permission is defined for special-use applications such as dialers, carrier applications, or ims applications. So how should ordinary applications handle it.

READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE
public static final String READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE
Allows read only access to precise phone state. Allows reading of detailed information about phone state for special-use applications such as dialers, carrier applications, or ims applications.

Constant Value: "android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE"

Comment: This is a comment and not an definitive answer. Please keep comments to the post itself.