# TelephonyManager.EXTRA_FOREGROUND_CALL_STATE not found

Tags: android

I'm trying to work with PreciseCallState in API 22 project using Android Studio. There is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821952/how-to-use-precisecallstate) on SO -

```
public class OutCallLogger extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (intent.getIntExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_FOREGROUND_CALL_STATE, -2) {
        case PreciseCallState.PRECISE_CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
            break;
        case PreciseCallState.PRECISE_CALL_STATE_DIALING:
            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "DIALING");
            break;
        case PreciseCallState.PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ALERTING:
            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "ALERTING");
            break;
        case PreciseCallState.PRECISE_CALL_STATE_ACTIVE:
            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "ACTIVE");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

But it gives error - `cannot find symbol variable EXTRA_FOREGROUND_CALL_STATE`.
What I am missing here? I am a new comer in android world.

Comment: You need to either use Reflection or a custom android.jar - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134331/cannot-detect-when-outgoing-call-is-answered-in-android