# intent at call pickup

Tags: android, android-intent, incoming-call

My problem is that while using the app, the incoming call UI/Intent is shown minimized on the status bar.

[image]

Instead, I want to show it like this -

[image]

I'm calling the intent ACTION_ANSWER but it seems to be not working.

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

or is there any way I can maximize the Incoming call UI?

Comment: have you tried not setting any flags?

Comment: @the7th I'm using this code in a service & a service needs to pass those flags.

Comment: @TimCastelijns It does not solve my problem. I need to bring this intent to the front instead of hiding it normally which is done default.

Answer (score 0):

> public static final String ACTION_ANSWER
>
> Added in API level 1 Activity Action: Handle an incoming phone call.
>
> Input: nothing.
>
> Output: nothing.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.ANSWER"

Please check below link for demo case

1. [CustomIncomingCallScreen](https://github.com/inez/CustomIncomingCallScreen)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1

Comment: The link you provided is trying to replace the default screen with custom built intent but what I want is to bring the default UI of incoming call to the front. I don't want to build my own, just want to show the default UI when it is minimized.