# How to auto accept calls on android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to Answer the call programmatically and accept DTMF input on phone? Think about it as small hard-coded IVR on mobile device. 
I tried looking for docs but could find any.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27084305/4427731 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16221978/4427731 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This only really answers part of your question but you will need a `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive notifications of call state.  For example you would have something like following in `AndroidManfest.xml` and then, in broadcast receiver, check for `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` state.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="MyPhoneStateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```